# SQLite: Select one row or return NULL when no row satisfies conditions

Tags: sqlite

I want to `INSERT OR REPLACE` a row specified by 'uuid' column value. There is what I have:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO feature_layer (id, uuid, feature_collection)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM feature_layer WHERE uuid=?) , ?, GeomFromGeoJSON(?));
```

Will this query do what I want, which means update row specified by uuid or insert new one if no such row is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming that your *id* field is defined as ***(with AUTOINCREMENT)***

  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

the correct statement will be

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO feature_layer (id, uuid, feature_collection)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM feature_layer WHERE uuid=?), ?, GeomFromGeoJSON(?));
```

(you missed one `(` in your query)

- If your *id* field is defined as ***(without AUTOINCREMENT)***

  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

you will want to use `COALESCE` to set a new *id* (I have added one `?` for the new *id*) if no records are found:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO feature_layer (id, uuid, feature_collection)
VALUES (COALESCE((SELECT id FROM feature_layer WHERE uuid=?),?) , ?, GeomFromGeoJSON(?));
```

---

With the above queries, as you want, you will update *uuid* and *feature_collection* when the *id* matches the one filtered by *uuid*, and if no records are found, then it will insert a new record with your desired values for uuid and feature_collection.

Anyway, take into account that your *id* field must be the `PRIMARY KEY` to use this method.